# .NET keep application alive while waiting for task to complete

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, task, exit

I just inherited a c# 4.0 WinForms app (basically just a small dashboard) that uses a producer-consumer pattern.  My consumer task (literally System.Threading.Tasks.Task) is processing data in a queue.  When the user wants to shut down the app, the producer (a TCP socket server) is stopped immediately.  However, the queue may not be empty so I need to give the user the option to exit immediately or exit as soon as the consumer task has finished processing all of the queued data.  If the user wants to wait for the consumer task to finish, the UI naturally needs to remain responsive.  The problem I'm having is that since the code to exit the application resides in the click event handler for the "Exit" button, I may need to wait for the consumer task to finish while I'm inside the click event handler.  In a nutshell, the event handler contains this (very ugly) code:

```
  // loop while there is still data in the queue
  while (QueuedData.Count > 0)
  {
    Application.DoEvents(); // UI is semi-responsive but with a lot of CPU utilization)
  }

  // the queue is empty so now exit the application
```

Can anyone suggest an alternate way of implementing this functionality so that I'm not stuck in tight loop inside of an event handler on the UI thread?  Would it make any sense to start another thread/task at this point to handle this checking and then shut down the app from that thread?  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an Exit task that is queued in the same queue [by the Exit button]
 - when the queue is finished, the Exit handler would be called.

If you wanted, you could update the UI to say 'Exit pending...' in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I decided to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Handle close event, cancel it, add continuation to task that closes form.

Answer (score 0):

also using a loop like that might be quite CPU intensive as you have mentioned. Why not use Observer pattern to the full so that:

- subscriber will listen for updates and queue it up in the BlockingCollection (or any other Blocking collection)
- another background thread will wait for items in the above queue and process it as it comes along

On shutdown:

- you stop publishing to the queue;
- you can find out how many items you got in the queue and inform the via GUI so that user can choose to wait for force close if needed

[MSDN link on BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)